# Centering form into a div block

Tags: css, html

The following form and css stylesheet are given:

`index.html` snippet

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <form>
            <input type="text"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="helper"></div>
</div>
```

`mycss.css` snippet

```
.parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #dd0;
    background: #ffa;
}
.child {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.helper {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    width:0px;
}
```

[There is result](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/em7kf/) of code above. But this result isn't clear for me. What is the role of `div.helper` in this example?

In the `div.parent` style class we have `text-align: center;`. Why without it we have only horizontal centering?

Why without `vertical-align:middle;` in the `div.child` or `div.helper` we have only horizontal centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here `div.helper` is used in `display:inline-block` & `vertcal-align:middle` mode to make the other one **vertically middle** to the `.parent`.

And

`text-align: center;` is used to make the input elements center to `.parent`

As said in top,

`vertcal-align:middle` is used to make those elements vertically center to `.parent`.

But there were other **simple, clean and better ways** to do this

Either You can use this simple method to do this:

**just change CSS ike this:**

Apply `diplay:table-cell;` to `.parent` div, So that it will get the ability to align its child vertically middle.

then apply `vertical-align:middle` to the same to make the child elements vertcally middle

```
.parent {
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #dd0;
background: #ffa;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**and remove all other CSS and `.helper` div**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/em7kf/2/)**

Comment: There are better, cleaner ways to do this, as you point out. In today's web development world (where nobody supports IE7 anymore) - we'd typically style a pseudo element, (or perhaps use `display: table-cell;`) to accomplish this. No unnecessary markup.

Comment: @Dmitrii check mu updated answer, you can find another way there

Comment: Actually, I'd put `display:table` on `.parent`, and `display:table-cell` on `.child`, I find you'll maintain more control this way.